# Getting constant and enum values from C header files w/ calllib in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

So I'm using calllib to call into my shared library. Everything is working well with that.

One of the C header files I pass to loadlibrary has enum values. Is there any way to reference these enum values in matlab? Like

```
ret = calllib('mylib','foo',x);
if (ret == libenum('mylib','returnSuccess'))...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking for the same and found no such thing in the documentation. But since you can use the corresponding C enum strings in matlab that is actually simpler than `libenum('mylib','returnSuccess')`. You can just do

```
if( ret == 'returnSuccess' )
```

However it's clear that matlab itself knows the enums since using `libfunctionsview` shows them by name. If you look in `loadlibrary` you'll see matlab basically preprocesses the header files and runs a perl script over it which creates an m-file containing the needed info. Including enums. For example I have a C enum with Failed and Success items, here is the corresponding m-code created by the perl script:

```
enuminfo.tagResult=struct('Failed',0,'Success',1);
```

This script is evaluated in `loadlibrary` and creates a struct `enums` containing all enums. So if you extract the parts needed to get there you get all info you need. I'll leave the actual work up to you though, but simply modifying the loadlibrary function definition would actually be sufficient, be it not very maintainance-friendly. If you change the definition to

```
function [notfound,warnings,enums]=loadlibrary(library,header,varargin)
```

it will happily return the enums struct and you can use them like

```
enums.tagResult.Failed
```